# How to inject HTML code into every delivered HTML page?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, rewrite, html

I've got an `Apache web server` that delivers static HTML pages. For some reason I can't change the files themselves, but I still want to inject some HTML into every page that is being served.

Is this possible with `mod_proxy`? If not, could anyone recommend a software 
that provides such a feature?

EDIT: 
I have to insert some kind of banner ad (e.g. a `javascript`) and a tracking pixel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do this: Work with mod_rewrite to change requests from

```
/some/static/page.html
```

to

```
/htmlinjector.php?url=/some/static/page.html
```

then use PHP (or whatever you find appropriate) to do the file-manipulation. Add an output cache to improve performance.

As an alternative, [Apache Handlers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/handler.html) sound helpful:

> **Modifying static content using a CGI
>   script**
>
> The following directives will cause
>   requests for files with the `html`
>   extension to trigger the launch of the
>   `footer.pl` CGI script.
>
> ```
> Action add-footer /cgi-bin/footer.pl
> AddHandler add-footer .html
> ```
>
> Then the CGI script is responsible for
>   sending the originally requested
>   document (pointed to by the
>   `PATH_TRANSLATED` environment variable)
>   and making whatever modifications or
>   additions are desired.

This is more or less what the mod_rewrite approach would do, only with less hackery.

Comment: Can someone give an example of the mod_rewrite solution? (specifically the content of htmlinjector.php)

Comment: For those of you struggling with this - don't forget `ScriptAlias` and `<Directory /some/static/>...</Directory>`,  `<Directory /path/to/cgi-bin/> Options +ExecCGI</Directory>`etc. I don't want to tamper with the user's answer but if you request, I will give more info.

Comment: @asdf Example: `<?php ob_start(); include("/some/static/page.html"); $contents = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); echo str_replace('</head>', '<script async>Some script content goes here like adsense code</script></head>', $contents) ?>`
use $content to load the rest of the page content. you can save this file as htmlinjector.php or whatever and call it in your htaccess file like this: `Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /some/static/page.html RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /htmlinjector.php?url=/some/static/page.html`

Answer (score 21):

I am not sure why this hasn't been mentioned in the list of answer. Sorry if it took me 2 years to see this question...

The easiest, most powerful way to do what you want to do what you want is using an [Apache filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ext_filter.html).

Just have:

```
ExtFilterDefine css_changer mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/some/php/script.php"
SetOutputFilter css_changer
```

A possible script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?

#phpinfo(); // Uncomment to see ALL env variables
$host = $_ENV["HTTP_HOST"]; // www.site.com
$script_name = $_ENV["SCRIPT_NAME"]; // /theme/green/style.css
$pi = pathinfo($script_name);
$type = $pi['extension'];
#print "$host $script  $type";

$stdin = STDIN;

while($line = fgets($stdin)){
  $line = preg_replace('/a/', 'A', $line);

  fwrite(STDOUT, $line);
}
fclose(STDOUT);
?>
```

This will change all "a"s into "A"s .

Be sure to enable filter in your httpd.conf, like this:

```
LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
```

This question ranks really up in Google and there isn't much out there in terms of forums

Comment: That's by far the best solution, i was able to find for a similar problem. Thanks very much for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a tutorial](http://ckdake.com/node/235) on how to use [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) to edit the links on a webpage ( the content).  You might be able to apply this modify the html you want.

UPDATE:
Are you sure you want to go this route?  I think Apache is meant to serve content, not create it.  This would probably go in the view part of a MVC framework.  The reason I wouldn't recommend this is you are breaking [the rule of modularity](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html#id2877537).  Your web application will be intertwined with the application that server it, complicating future upgrades, moves, etc.

Comment: Hm, if I get it right mod_proxy_html is not capable to add complete new code snipets?

Comment: Not sure, now that you have added more, Commander Tomalak's answer sounds better.  You are in the land of hackery I would say, creating web pages isn't really what Apache is for, it is for serving up content.

Comment: I tought that there is maybe some kind of standalone proxy which could rewrite html pages. Something like MySQL Proxy for MySQL. Maybe Privoxy could do this.

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: LOL - I think the mention of the military rank officially makes you a trekkie. This made my day. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to do this with mod_rewrite and SSI.

First put the path into an environment variable

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^(/.*\.html) /page.shtml [E=filename:$1]
```

then process that in the shtml file

```
<!--#include virtual="$filename"-->
```

Parts of this solution are based on a stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133/getting-apache-to-modify-static-webpages-on-the-fly/1196832 )

Comment: My main reason to want to use shtml for this would be that calling an external CGI for each request might cause load problems.

Answer (score 4):

[mod_sed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_sed.html) is a good fit here.  You can create an output filter that matches the closing head or body tag, for example, and insert your html before it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache mod_substitute to inject html into outgoing responses using some criteria or regular expressions.
[**Here**](http://www.objectmasters.com/Blog/Post/How-to-Inject-html-in-outgoing-responses-from-Apache-Proxy) is an explanation of how to achieve this.

Comment: Link is dead,,,

Answer (score 1):

Would a mod_perl module be any use?

http://search.cpan.org/~gozer/Apache2-Layout-0.6/lib/Apache2/Layout.pm

That might do what you want or, at least, point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thx, I'll have a look, at the moment we tend to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/handler.html with a custom footer.pl

Answer (score 1):

you can look into the header and footer directive of apache, Using the directives below.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/data/scott">
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    AddOutputFilter LAYOUT html htm shtml
    LayoutComment On
    LayoutHeader /wrappers/scott-header.html
    LayoutFooter /wrappers/scott-footer.html
</Directory>
```

More reading is here: 
[http://wannabe.guru.org/scott/hobbies/apache/](https://web.archive.org/web/20090717094555/http://wannabe.guru.org/scott/hobbies/apache/)

Answer (score 1):

Mod Layout is now obsolete and if you don't want the overhead of calling an external script, the best solution which worked for me was [mod sed](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_sed.html).
You can use mod sed to match first line of doc (1s) and add header script code there and match last line ($s) and put footer there.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from none
Allow from all
Require all granted

AddOutputFilter Sed html
SetOutputFilter Sed;DEFLATE
OutputSed "1s|^|<header code>|"
OutputSed "$s|$|</footer code>|g"
```

Comment: On a shared hosting server this may not be available. Anyway how would one find the closing body tag and insert a Google Analytics code just before it?

Answer (score 0):

i can insert html to all pages via Apache, but only for site that hosted by my apache, not all site though my apache proxy server.

this is how it work. i set up an XAMPP, download mod_layout 5.1 for apache 2.4. (install mod_layout is simple, if you use XAMPP for windows, just download mod_layout.so 5.1 for windows and put it to your apache module folder $home/apache/module, then add the config DSO to your httpd.conf LoadModule layout_module modules/mod_layout.so - if you using linux or other os, you should download mod_layout.so for linux, then run make command to install)

After install mod_layout.so for windows, just put this code on your .htaccess file or httpd.conf your will get html insert to all your page:

```
<IfModule mod_layout.c>
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT html 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT htm 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT shtml 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT shtm 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT cgi 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT php 
LayoutFooter "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/footer.php"
</IfModule>
```

C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/footer.php is where you put your html or php file, in my situation is C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/footer.php, but you can put it any where, just give the right path, you'll be fine