# How to modify outgoing traffic

Tags: debian

I'm running Calibre with its Calibre Content Server on Debian. This serves webpages which show a book library, including the ability to both download books and to read the books in the browser. I would like to remove the download button, and there is no option in the Calibre server to remove it. While its open source and I suppose I could dig through the code, remove it there, and recompile from source, I figured there must be a way to modify things the system is serving.

I read (here: [How to inject HTML code into every delivered HTML page?](https://serverfault.com/questions/46449/how-to-inject-html-code-into-every-delivered-html-page)) about using mod_rewrite or an Apache filter to do this kind of thing, but as far as I understand, that would only work for things I am serving from Apache, not from other applications like Calibre.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up `nginx` as a proxy (see [proxy_pass](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)) in front of it and use this module 
https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

> The ngx_http_sub_module module is a filter that modifies a response by
>   replacing one specified string by another

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect. I think that will do exactly what I am looking for.